Extending bot context in typescript
I have a standard express app with bot framework like this:
const teamsBot = new TeamsBot();
app.post('/api/messages', async (req, res) => {
  await commandApp.requestHandler(req, res, async (context) => {
    await teamsBot.run(context);
  });
});

is there possibility to somehow extend context - for example add prisma there or attach graphql client, etc.?
